# Need help making sense of varying time values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I routinely get data in a time field column on an Excel spreadsheet that I need to convert into basic numbers such as 6, 7, 8.

**Here's an example of the mess I get:**

*(Note: I cannot change how the data is received)*

```
Time
-------------------------------
8am
10am
9:00 am (no early birds please)
8:00
9 a.m Sharp
7:00 am
8am-2pm
9 am
8AM TO 3PM
08-10-2018 9am
7:30am, 8:30 am
Any
9am
8AM TO 3PM
Today thru sun
10:00 a.m.
```

I recently ran some code that would pull out all numbers from the cell, then remove everything except the first number and that's somewhat close but...

The perfect scenario would be code to output the desired numbers and if cell data wouldn't comply with the code intent (error), a message box would open allowing edits, or, the cell would be flagged with a color so I knew where to look. I end up with about 500 lines of these cells to ferret through. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help to format your data so it matches the way you receive it.

Comment: This is text comprehension, not mere parsing algorithm. Any decent machine learning product can resolve this issue, e.g. the text comprehension services of IBM Watson or Microsoft Cortana. If you really need to do this in Excel, then I'd say you have to define all possible scenarios and then put all of them into a parser. I would cut the string into substrings along digit/character-blocks, identifying ":" or "a.m." etc. as a time and everything else as "other".

Comment: So it looks to me like you're receiving data from a bunch of users. If they're inputting theyre data themselves directly into excel, you could consider putting data validation in place so that they have to choose certain options to keep your data clean

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I haven't considered the text comprehension aspect.  I'll look into it.  I'm scraping the data so I don't have much control of its input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are considering text comprehension, here's a cheap and dirty VBA function that might get a fair chunk of your cases.  I would implement this in combination with conditional formatting that highlights cells greater than or equal to one or zero. (My example screenshot has such formatting in place.)

```
Public Function GetDate(DateVal As String) As Date

Dim returnDate As Date    ' Date to be returned
Dim cleanedDate As String ' Working string containing the candidate date
Dim wordIndex As Integer  ' Counter for walking through the word array
Dim wordArray() As String ' Working string broken into words

' Initialize to zero date
returnDate = CDate(0)

If IsNumeric(DateVal) Then
    ' Handle dates already converted
    returnDate = CDate(DateVal)
Else
    ' Eliminate spurious characters
    cleanedDate = UCase(Replace(Replace(Replace(DateVal, ".", ""), ",", " "), "-", " "))

    If IsDate(cleanedDate) Then
        ' If CDate can fix it, just do that.
        returnDate = TimeValue(CDate(cleanedDate))
    Else
        wordArray() = Split(cleanedDate, " ")
        If UBound(wordArray) > 0 Then
            wordIndex = 0
            ' Look through each word and return the first time found
            Do Until returnDate > 0 Or wordIndex = UBound(wordArray)
                If IsDate(wordArray(wordIndex)) Then
                    returnDate = CDate(wordArray(wordIndex))
                End If
                wordIndex = wordIndex + 1
            Loop
        End If
    End If
End If

GetDate = returnDate

End Function
```

Here is what I get with your sample data in column A and `=PERSONAL.XLSB!GetDate(A1)` (or equivalent) in column B:

[image: Results of Running Function]

Note that rows 4, 6, and 8 show time values. This is because Excel converted the values when I pasted your sample data in place. The function handles values that Excel automatically converts.

Fixing Row 5 in code could get tricky. You'll have to weigh that coding effort against the simple manual fix of deleting the space between 9 and a.m.

The code gets about 80% of your example cases. If the ratio holds for your overall data, you're looking at manually adjusting roughly 100 cells. If you're doing this regularly, consider further tweaking of the code. One last ditch effort might be to walk through the string from left to right character by character to see if you can find and build a time string.

...or, of course, you can use text comprehension as mentioned above. :-)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! That definitely helps.